# How to disable automatic change of browser mode in IE9?

Tags: internet-explorer-9

How could I use IE9 with permanent "Browser mode" and "Document mode"?

I want to use IE9 mode all the time, because I am developing an add-on that work only with IE9 mode, I need to force my browser to be in IE9 mode, instead of changing the mode again and again,
Is there API for IE9 that allow me to set the mode?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try adding

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge" />
```

to document HEAD.

This makes IE work in standart document mode for latest IE mode.